# OSX File Renaming Issue

Tags: macos, script, finder, applescript

We have over 15000 images that need renaming.

Is there a simple way to **find** text in a file name (from a csv file) and **replace** text in a file name (again from a csv file)??

Eg. **File Name - AA021 asphalt/fuchsia FRONT.jpg**

We have a CSV of full names "asphalt" and a CSV of short names "ASP" etc.

So **FINAL** File Name would be - **AA021 ASP/FUS FRONT.jpg**

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a third party tool called "A Better Finder Rename", incredible versatile.
http://www.publicspace.net/ABetterFinderRename/

Comment: This does not answer the question as asked nor from what I see can "A Better Finder Rename" do what was asked, namely "find text in a file name (from a csv file) and replace text in a file name (again from a csv file)".